# SSRS Dynamic page headers; web vs print rendering?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, header

The dynamic headers in the web rendering version work just fine, but when I look at the print preview, only the very first page renders correctly, the rest just render the hard coded part

This is the expression I’m using:
=First(ReportItems("Location").Value)+ " Court Calendar"

Any idea why the web version and the print preview render differently?

also, location is the first of three groups in the grouping pane